# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input=[id*=chkSendOut]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Whenever i try to load the page the following alert pops up,

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input=[id*=chkSendOut]

code :

```
if ($('#' + this.id).find("'input=[id*=chkSendOut]'").length == 0) {
```

im using code lines like these , is there any error in this?

Comment: I am trying to update the jquery version to latest and im stuck with the above error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove that unnecessary `equals to` after input,

```
if ($('#' + this.id).find("input[id*=chkSendOut]").length == 0) {
//-----------------------------^
```

And that is causing the error, since it is an invalid selector. Please read here to know more about [attribute contains selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

And as [satpal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668533/satpal) said, The single quote that you included inside the selector would also cause the error. Remove it too.

Comment: Also remove ambiguous quotes would be better. `"input[id*=chkSendOut]"`

Comment: removed the equals,still not working, it says :Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 'input[id*=chkSendOut]'

Comment: @user3732989 Please see the edited version of the answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're trying to target current element using an id selector, which seems unnecessary. you can directly access it using `this`.

`$('#' + this.id)` is equivalent to `$(this)` since both selects the current element

Also add the quotes correctly -

try

```
if ($(this).find('input[id*="chkSendOut"]').length == 0) {
```